# from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

Tags: python, import, filenames, huggingface-transformers, tqdm

I am running this code:

I have these updated packages versions:
tqdm-4.65.0 transformers-4.27.4

I am running this code:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

I am obtaining this erros:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ObjectWrapper' from 'tqdm.utils' (/Users/anitasancho/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/utils.py)

Answer (score 0):

I solved from the terminal window by:
Create a new virtual environment using `conda` with the following command:

```
conda create --name mi_entorno python=3.7
```

Then, activate the virtual environment with the following command:

```
conda activate mi_entorno
```

Then import again, and it worked!